# Winforms. Не слушается кнопка: игнорирует команду смены состояния

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

Впервые столкнулся с непослушанием программы на Winforms:

```
btn.Enabled = true; // было false, отрабатывает корректно - стало true
btn.Visible = true; // было false, отрабатывает неправильно - остается false
```

Исключений не вылетает.
Пробовал вызывать

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
```

до, посередине и после 1го блока кода. Не помогает.

Что с программой не так?

Вот более полная версия кода:

```
foreach (Button btn in buttonsList)
{
    btn.Visible = false;
    btn.Enabled = false;
    btn.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    btn.BackgroundImage = null;

    btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
    btn.Margin = new Padding(0, 5, 0, 5);
}

foreach (string num in _list)
{
    foreach (Button btn in buttonsList)
    {
        if(btn.Text == num)
        {
            // Вот на этом моменте уже не работает
            btn.Enabled = true; 
            btn.Visible = true; 
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Чудес не бывает в нашем деле :) проверьте события, посмотрите, скорее всего где-то ещё меняется на false; Либо вы где-то в foreach это делаете и нечаянно сбиваете снова. В общем приведите более подробный код события Click.

Comment: а контейнер в котором лежит кнопка видим? именно видим, а не какое значение у свойства Visible.

Comment: @4per Да, контейнер виден

Comment: Может просто условие не выполняется?

Comment: @koks_rs Условие точно выполняется, прохожу под дебагом и наблюдаю за свойством Visible, и оно не меняется

Comment: Сделайте по дефолту одну кнопку видимой и попробуйте скрыть. Есть подозрение, что вы обрабатываете свой массив кнопок, не относящихся к форме. Так же можете попробовать поместить "более полную версию кода" в lock

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что кнопки находились на панели

Панель лежала в еще одной панели

Родительская панель лежала в userControl

userControl лежал на форме

И проблема была в том, что userControl был disabled и из-за этого изменение свойств наследников было заблокировано. Но userControl визуально отображался, а одна из его панелей нет